# Convert date format in file on specific column from +"%Y-%m-%d" to +"%d-%m-%Y"

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am running a bash script, which outputs this:

```
2019-06-05 08:30 99432434
2019-06-05 10:00 99432465
2019-06-05 11:00 97987567
2019-06-05 12:00 97433556
2019-06-05 13:15 96844558
2019-06-05 17:00 97091234
2019-06-05 18:00 96764765
2019-06-05 19:00 99878787
```

I want to convert the date format in the first column to be like this:

```
05-06-2019 08:30 99432434
05-06-2019 10:00 99432465
05-06-2019 11:00 97987567
05-06-2019 12:00 97433556
05-06-2019 13:15 96844558
05-06-2019 17:00 97091234
05-06-2019 18:00 96764765
05-06-2019 19:00 99878787
```

So basically it has to become `+"%d-%m-%Y"`, whereas now it's `+"%Y-%m-%d"`.

I tried piping the output of the command to this:

```
while read -r line; do echo $(date -d "$line" +%Y-%m-%d); done
```

But it goes through the whole file, and it results in this:

```
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 08:30 99432434
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 10:00 99432465
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 11:00 97987567
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 12:00 97433556
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 13:15 96844558
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 17:00 97091234
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 18:00 96764765
date: invalid date 2019-06-06 19:00 99878787
```

How can I change the date format of the first column to `+"%d-%m-%Y"`?

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to do that? You convert your file from a perfectly sortable format to a perfectly unsortable format. I understand you must have your reasons ... but I just wanted to point out that sooner or later you might realize that a good ISO format is better than a locally used format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a fixed format, you can do away with date manipulation and simply use `awk` to shuffle the fields around:

```
awk -F'[- ]' '{ print $3"-"$2"-"$1" "$4" "$5 }' file
```

outputs

```
05-06-2019 08:30 99432434
05-06-2019 10:00 99432465
05-06-2019 11:00 97987567
05-06-2019 12:00 97433556
05-06-2019 13:15 96844558
05-06-2019 17:00 97091234
05-06-2019 18:00 96764765
05-06-2019 19:00 99878787
```

Answer (score 1):

With any sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(....\)\(....\)\(..\)/\3\2\1/' file
05-06-2019 08:30 99432434
05-06-2019 10:00 99432465
05-06-2019 11:00 97987567
05-06-2019 12:00 97433556
05-06-2019 13:15 96844558
05-06-2019 17:00 97091234
05-06-2019 18:00 96764765
05-06-2019 19:00 99878787
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the first column into one variable (`$d` below), and the rest into another (`$rest` below):

```
while read -r d rest; do echo $(date -d "$d" +%d-%m-%Y) $rest; done
```

Comment: I added your suggestion but it didn't change the date. This is the script. https://pastebin.com/a7h07JRb

Comment: Ah, yeah, I copied and pasted your script which had the wrong date format. I've updated.

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for some of the issues with that script.

Comment: See path-of-least-resistance and best-use-of-ones-time

Comment: The path of least resistance and best use of one's time is to ignore the question completely but if you're not going to do that and decide to provide an answer instead then IMHO you should give people reading the answer (now and in future) a heads up if there are well-know, common issues in the resulting script, especially if doing so is as easy as providing links to existing articles on the issues. I doubt if the OP knew about those issues until now given the script she provided in her question.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the best use of my time, but I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU `date`, you can use the `-f` option to read multiple dates from a file and invoke `date` just once; combined with `cut`, `paste` and process substitution, you get something like

```
paste -d ' ' \
    <(date -f <(cut -d' ' -f1  infile) '+%d-%m-%Y') \
    <(cut -d' ' -f2- infile)
```

Comment: So this is how you would do it?

Comment: @SeanBright Probably, if I had the exact problem? Unless we're talking about maaaaany lines, there won't be a noticeable difference between any of the approaches here.